# Using PHP Variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working with a template and the JavaScript is in a separate .js file with hard values.  I want to make the values change based on a MySQL query and PHP variables that are in my php file.

I looked up several similar answers and they incorporate the .js code within the html, not creating variables within the .js code (if that is even the best route).

HTML:

`<div class="padded"><div id="piechart" style=""> </div> </div>`

JS:

```
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'piechart',
    data: [
      {label: 'Option 1', value: 25 },
      {label: 'Option 2', value: 40 },
      {label: 'Option 3', value: 25 },
      {label: 'Option 4', value: 10 }
    ],
    colors: ["#3228db", "#34225e", "#1abc3c", "#24495e", "#9b51b6", "#15a5a6"],
    formatter: function (y) { return y + "%" }
 });
```

I want to change the values in the js script to match variables from PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, @EugenRiek, for editing. Was about to do the same ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. Had to do it twice - OP overwrote my first attempt

Answer (score 0):

First: keep in mind that PHP is executed serverside, way before the browser receives any javascript it can execute. SO: what you're asking for is only possible, if the variables you need are known before the user does anything - otherwise you'd need AJAX to get new values from the server and should really do some reading on it.

If you got the variables, you can simply output the javascript using PHP. I assumed it'S the "value" attribute of those objects you want to change, and I assumed that the values you got from your database are stored in an array named `$values` - just replace it by whatever you really got.

```
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'piechart',
    data: [
      {label: 'Option 1', value: <?php echo $values[0] ?> },
      {label: 'Option 2', value: <?php echo $values[0] ?>},
      {label: 'Option 3', value: <?php echo $values[0] ?>},
      {label: 'Option 4', value: <?php echo $values[0] ?>}
    ],
    colors: ["#3228db", "#34225e", "#1abc3c", "#24495e", "#9b51b6", "#15a5a6"],
    formatter: function (y) { return y + "%" }
});
```

Comment: This will not work, as the `.js` file never goes through PHP, making the `<?php echo $values[0] ?>` pointless

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree on that. It's common practice and works fine. a) OP didn't say that it is a separate file.
b) YOu can configure the server to parse .js
c) there is no requirement to name javascript files .js - you can have a .php file outputting javascript code and send it with a context type of "text/javascript".

Comment: Oh, sorry. Op statet it is a separate file. b) and c) still stay valid though ;)

Comment: Just to make that clear: I didn't object to creating JS files from PHP, in fact - as you pointed out - this is quite a common strategy. My objection was to the specific implementation, where OP mentioned the JS being both static and separate

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here, the easiest (but not most elegant) would be something like

HTML:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">

function getPiechartData() {

  //The folllowing is created via the template from MySQL

  return [
      {label: 'Option 1', value: 25 },
      {label: 'Option 2', value: 40 },
      {label: 'Option 3', value: 25 },
      {label: 'Option 4', value: 10 }
    ];
}

</script>
...
```

JS:

```
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'piechart',
    data: getPiechartData(),
    colors: ["#3228db", "#34225e", "#1abc3c", "#24495e", "#9b51b6", "#15a5a6"],
    formatter: function (y) { return y + "%" }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to emit the values from PHP *as JavaScript*; then it will be available in your external scripts.  For example:

**PHP**

```
<script>
    // option1 and option2 are numeric
    var option1 = <?php echo $option1; ?>;
    var option2 = <?php echo $option2; ?>;
    var colors = [
        <?php echo '"' . implode( '", "', $colors ) . '"'; ?>
    ]
</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

Then, in `external.js`, the (JavaScript) variables `option1`, `option2`, and `colors` will be available.

You also might want to consider putting your variables in a single object so you're not cluttering up your global space with variables:

**PHP**

```
<script>
    // option1 and option2 are numeric
    var stuff = {
        option1: <?php echo $option1; ?>,
        option2: <?php echo $option2; ?>,
        colors = [
            <?php echo '"' . implode( '", "', $colors ) . '"'; ?>
        ]
    }
</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
```